# Can one I drop multiple controls in window builder at once?

Tags: java, swt, windowbuilder

Is it possible to drop more than one control at once in window builder?

I tried the obvious combinations of mouse drag and drop with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd> but could not find it as of yet.

[image: windowbuilder drag and drop]

(Unfortunately the mouse cursor was not captured when I was dragging "New Label".)

Comment: Have you tried holding shift while you select the controls to move?

Comment: Are you trying to drop multiple labels at once or do you want to select multiple widgets from the "left" and drop them to the "right"?

Comment: @ChrisCooney please create an answer out of your comment. Except one needs to press ctrl instead of shit while selecting the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press  <kbd>ctrl</kbd> while selecting the control from the toolbox to drop the control multiple times.